# Error in Google Tag Manager - The workspace has the following errors

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm getting the following error when I try to publish it:

[image: 1]

`<script> (function(ss,ex){ window.ldfdr=window.ldfdr||function(){(ldfdr._q=ldfdr._q||[]).push([].slice.call(arguments));}; (function(d,s){ fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; function ce(src){ var cs=d.createElement(s); cs.src=src; cs.async=1; fs.parentNode.insertBefore(cs,fs); }; ce(‘https://sc.lfeeder.com/lftracker_v1_'+ss+(ex?'_'+ex:'')+'.js’); })(document,‘script’); })(‘kn9Eq4Ryyqj7RlvP’); </script>`

I haven't tried anything as I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

It is the error when copy from some document. The symbol `'` will become `‘` or `’`
You need to change all the `‘` `’` to `'`.

```
<script> (function(ss,ex){ window.ldfdr=window.ldfdr||function(){(ldfdr._q=ldfdr._q||[]).push([].slice.call(arguments));}; (function(d,s){ fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; function ce(src){ var cs=d.createElement(s); cs.src=src; cs.async=1; fs.parentNode.insertBefore(cs,fs); }; ce('https://sc.lfeeder.com/lftracker_v1_'+ss+(ex?'_'+ex:'')+'.js'); })(document,'script'); })('kn9Eq4Ryyqj7RlvP'); </script>
```